# Alt Tab (Task Switcher) randomly changing the specified row/columns configuration

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I have changed in the **Task Switcher** of my Windows 7 SP1 (Aero enabled) the row/columns config to 8 columns by editing `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\CoolSwitchColumns`, but changes **only work some times**.

This is the **correct** Alt+Tab splash screen (note the 8 columns):

[image]

but **more often** I get this other (note the strange way to show the 8th column and the 3rd row):

[image]

The correct task switcher is only shown about 1/6 times, mostly in a random way.
I have tested [Alt+Tab Tuner v1.0.11](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.5) too, with no success.

I know that I can go back to classic Windows XP task switcher´s style, but I would prefer to keep the modern way.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved! :-D

The problem came from [WinSize2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/), a windows **autoresizer**.

This is: the program works OK, but I have accidentally added the task *"Task Switcher"* to its database via the program's hotkey for that. So, **WinSize2 was resizing** that "window" too.

Hope this info will help anyone with my same problem.